# Excel 2007: Remove Dropshadow On Userform Window Using WinAPI

Tags: excel, winapi, border, userform, vba

I am using Excel 2007 VBA on a Windows 7 64-bit machine to create an Excel application.  I want a userform to be rendered without any title bar, border, or drop shadow.  I have succeeded in removing the title bar using the WinAPI.  It appears that no border is present, but that a drop shadow remains.  Here's an image of the userform window:

[image: Userform Window with Drop Shadow]

I have tried the following VBA code to remove the WS_BORDER from the userform window, but it doesn't seem to affect the drop shadow:

```
Sub HideWindowBorder(frm As Object)

'*** Dimesion Local Variables ***
Dim lngWindow As Long
Dim lngFrmHdl As Long

'*** Initialize Local Variables ***
lngFrmHdl = FindWindowA(vbNullString, frm.Caption)
lngWindow = GetWindowLong(lngFrmHdl, GWL_STYLE)
lngWindow = lngWindow And (Not WS_BORDER)

'*** Remove Border From Object Passed To This Sub ***
Call SetWindowLong(lngFrmHdl, GWL_STYLE, lngWindow)
Call UpdateWindow(lngFrmHdl)

End Sub
```

I'm stumped.  What should I be doing to remove all traces of any kind of "border," including a drop shadow?  I completely understand that the userform window will "disappear" into its background (in the attached image) which is EXCATLY what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: That is not a drop shadow.  Your form has a 3D border on it.  You are simply seeing the dark edge of that border (if you look more closely, you can also see the white of the light edge, too).  Use `(Get|Set)WindowLong()` to remove the `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE` style from the window's `GWL_EXSTYLE` value as well.

Comment: Isn't this a [WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543.aspx) border? At any rate, when changing a window's border, you should call [SetWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545.aspx) passing the `SWP_FRAMECHANGED` flag.

Comment: @IInspectable: `WS_THICKFRAME` is a sizable border, which is not what is being shown.  But you are right about sending `SWP_FRAMECHANGED`.

Comment: Isn't this `WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE` and not `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE`?

Comment: Remy Lebeau - You nailed it.  Thanks!  Would you mind posting this as an answer so I can give you credit?